# Call a Java class that is in a different Java file than the calling Java class

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04

So, I have a Java file called MinTest.java which contains a call to a class called Min which is located in another file called Min.java. Therefore, the layout is: The MinTest.java method calls the Min class that is in min.java.

I am compiling the code using "javac MinTest.java" but it does not work because it does not recognize Min.

How do I deal with this? I do not want to use an IDE, I need to compile and run everything from the command line. I am using ubuntu.
Thank you.

Comment: this is handled in about any textbook. Check the first few chapters.

Comment: Did you call it `Min.java` or `min.java`? They are quite different.

Comment: You need to study classpath, your javac needs a cp parameter

Comment: @DBQ if it was a classpath problem, java wouldn't be able to find class MinTest either.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException, you are right

Answer (score 0):

class Min shall be in Min.java, and to use it in another class Min.class shall be on compilation classpath  ( and of course, on execution classpath) -  consult javac documentation how to setup  it.    But  to be hones, you can as well do this in IDE. Almost nobody does compile manually. Use ant/maven/gradle/IIDE ofyour choice

Comment: Compiling your first few programs manually helps you understand how the jdk works. It's a useful exercise.

Comment: It was useful exercise 20  Years ago. After this we had  ant - and before ant we had make.